# php echo text using session variable, and unset session variable when other session variable is set?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am trying to use session variable rather than use jquery to perform the following function.
I have some text on my page invoice.php:

```
Text A
```

I am echoing this text as a header on my page by using a session variable when the user first goes to that page like so:

```
<?php $_SESSION['ref'] = '<div class="inv_ref"><h23>Text A</h23></div>'; ?>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['ref'])) {
echo $_SESSION['ref'];
unset($_SESSION['ref']); } ?>
```

However once the user submits the following form on that page:

```
<form action="include/process_invoice.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="partNumber" placeholder="e.g. PO012345" class="login_form" />  
<input type="submit" value="Upload Invoice" name="submit" class="file">
</form>
```

the form is then processed on my page 'process_invoice.php' and once done I echo out the two new sessions onto my page invoice.php:

```
    $_SESSION['message2'] = '<div id="message_box3"><div class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div><h23>Thank You!</h23><p>You have successfully submitted your invoice.</p> </div>';

    $_SESSION['ref2'] = '<div class="inv_ref"><h23>REF: 12345678</h23></div>';
    unset($_SESSION['ref']);

header("location:../invoice.php");
```

so as you can see I am trying to unset my session 'ref' which is my 'Text A' and hide this text so it is not visible when my session 'ref2' is visible?

Is this possible and if so can someone please show me where I am going wrong? thanks

Comment: Can you put an exit after the unset to see if it echoes then? And also try exiting before the unset. I think you've got a problem with a redirect.

Comment: You seem to really be struggling with your use of `$_SESSION`.  Why do you want to store thing in session only to immediately unset them after outputting as in your first example?  I would suggest removing the messaging and HTML and such out of session storage and simply have a variable like `$_SESSION['invoice_status']` that you can change in value for to represent where you are in the process (i.e. with values like 'submitted', 'processed', etc.).  You can simply change the status as needed and message conditionally based on that status.

Comment: *"I am trying to use session variable rather than use jquery to perform the following function."* - that doesn't actually make much sense from a logical standpoint, it's like saying "I'm trying to use a helicopter rather than a fishing rod to paint this fence" - fundamentally different things used in totally different ways.

Comment: what you mean when say "visible"? if you only want to clear the var , your code already do it. But if you are trying to remove some content that has already been printed on the page, unset the var will not do it.  Once printed, PHP will not change it without help from JavaScript, or reloading the page.

Comment: @LuisSimioni that is what I am trying to do, I want to be able to echo some text using a session variable the instant a user lands on the page and once they submit the form they are redirected back to the page and the text has changed from that which is stored in session 'ref' with that which is stored in session 'ref2'. I want to do it this way because if a user has javascript disabled the function still works

Comment: I think what you're attempting is to create *PHP Session Based Flash Messages* ? : http://www.phpdevtips.com/2013/05/simple-session-based-flash-messages/ ... there are plenty of articles *once you know what to search for!* : https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=php+session+message+flash

Comment: If you are reloading the page, when form is submmited you can replace `$_SESSION['ref']` content with the new one.  create a ref2 and unset ref is not really necessary.

Comment: @LuisSimioni do you know how I would replace it? would you please be able to show me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your invoice.php, replace this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['ref'])) {
 echo $_SESSION['ref'];
 unset($_SESSION['ref']); } ?>
```

for this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['ref2'])) {
echo $_SESSION['ref2'];
} else {
echo $_SESSION['ref'];
} ?>
```

When your invoice.php reload you will see `REF: 12345678` instead of `Text A`.